# Rails: group by and max, pluck removes select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

So, I am trying to find out author_ids of posts, whose latest post received 10-50 likes. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
Post.select('MAX(created_at) as created_at, author_id')
.group(:author_id)
.where('likes > 10')
.where('likes < 50')
```

And it's working just fine, but when I add `pluck[:author_id]` it removes the `SELECT MAX(` from select. How do I get only the `author_ids` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) does that, removes what's in `select`.

On the other hand, `map` does what you need.

```
Post.select('MAX(created_at) as created_at, author_id')
 .group(:author_id)
 .where('likes > 10')
 .where('likes < 50')
 .map(&:author_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
Post.where(likes: [10..50]).pluck[:author_id].uniq
```

it's a little different approach because I prefer to take advantage of `ruby` syntax instead of direct queries but it should work just fine